# Why doesn't Xcode always display a hint of parameter default value?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, code-hinting

Is there any rule when Xcode displays hint of the function/method with default parameter value?

Here's what I mean. For example, in `UIViewController` there's `present()` method with the signature like this:

```
func present(
    _ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController,
    animated flag: Bool,
    completion: (() -> Void)? = nil
)
```

When I type its name in Xcode, I'm only hinted of the full method declaration, including `completion` parameter, which can be omitted:

1. > present(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?)

However, let's create `present` method's copy:

```
func presentCopy(
    _ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController,
    animated flag: Bool,
    completion: (() -> Void)? = nil
) {...}
```

This time, Xcode informs about two possible versions of the method:

1. > presentCopy(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: Bool)
2. > presentCopy(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: Bool,
   >   completion: (() -> Void)?)

Where does this inconsistency come from?

Comment: they are internal rules I don't think you can alter with. what is the reason you are asking? And where is the incosistency exactly?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I'd like to know when I can omit a parameter and when not, without looking up every method in the documentation. Inconsistency lays in the fact that is sometimes gives you all possible shapes of a method, and sometimes just the fullest.

Comment: As far as I know this will only happen in swift and nt objective c. maybe because it is built on top of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is because you are defining the method in a pure Swift class whereas `present` method of `UIViewController` is defined in Objective-C class.

In Objective-C there is no concept of default parameter values.

Even the opposite is true. If you access your `presentCopy` method inside an Obj-C Class, the method declaration will have all the values and there will be only one method.

Comment: That was my first thought too.